# Execute Trigger as Login

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, impersonation

Is it possible to impersonate a login when running a trigger?

I able able to run `execute as 'username'` but not `execute as login='username'`

I can usee `execute as` as such

```
with EXECUTE AS  login='smr'
  select top 9 * from Phonelist.dbo.po
REVERT
```

I want to put this in a trigger by I get a syntax error. My trigger loos like

```
ALTER TRIGGER triggername ON TableName
with execute as login = "USER_A" 
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @var varchar(20)SELECT TOP 1 @var = columnname FROM DATABASE_B.dbo.TABLE_B
END
```

Comment: With regards to which dbms?

Comment: I want to run that on SQLServer

Comment: Which version, and can you post the entire statement in which you use an `EXECUTE AS` clause?  I don't know of any syntax that includes `login=...`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're looking for on the [`ALTER TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) command is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER ON tableName WITH EXECUTE AS 'loginName'
```